# Dojotoolkit watch() not working on switch

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.mobile

I have a very annoying problem with watch() method from Dojo toolkit. I have a loop, that connects every input/widget in settings view (TweetView) with corresponding object. Connecting in my case is setting input to value from object and watch it for changes.

My problem is, that it works great for slider, but doesn't trigger handler for switch at all. Any ideas what could be wrong? I tried to debug it, but still no results. Here is a fiddle and the code:

```
var widget = registry.byId(namespace + "." + el);
widget.watch("value", handlers[root[el].type]);
widget.set("value", root[el].value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Em8GE/1/

Thanks in advice,

Dracco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is unfortunately a known issue in dojo 1.9.0 and 1.9.1: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17295

This is already fixed on dojox main branch and will be released in 1.9.2. The fix is detailed here: https://github.com/dojo/dojox/commit/43af4ba56f7b589f2afffb9161e21cc2cad40ad8